# functions with SOQL at the dataloader level

Tags: soql, force.com

I want to do a **dataloader**, and I'm struggling with a query. I'm running a  long query on Opportunity, and they want to pull fields from account and opp.  for all the opps on the account, they want to "sum" the values. can i do this given opp and account aren't an MDR?

```
 account.id     account.name     amount (from Opp)     custom_#__c (from opp)
 a              abc                 100                             1
 a              abc                 200                             2
 b              DEF                 1000                            100
```

output

```
account.id     account.name     amount (from Opp)     custom_#__c (from opp)
 a              abc                 300                             3
 b              DEF                 1000                            100
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Account and Opportunity are part of a MDR relationship - so you can definitely do rollups from Opportunity to Account. As such, I think you can just add two rollups to Account from Opty, and include that the Account Export?

Comment: they're more not really mdr- they're closer to lookups, right? anyway, do you have a suggestion?

Comment: No, they are MDR and you can create rollups on Opp from Accounts.

Comment: how do i do this in dataloader?

Comment: this is not done in data loader.  you create rollup summary fields on the account object that rolls up that data from the opps.  Then you have the data on the account and just use the data loader as you normally would.

Comment: there's too much in the where clause to do do the conditions at the "field level"

Comment: If you dont want to do this at the field level, then why wouldn't you use batch apex for this.  You can have your long and complicated Where statement, and update the account based on its underlying Opps.  I think the bottom line here, is everyone is saying that this is not something you would do with the dataloader.  And bolding the term dataloader in the question, doesn't change that